# Is there anyway to extract the data from okPacket from SQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i have this piece of code that add a new user to the database

```
let newAccount = {userName: data.userName, userEmail: data.userEmail.toLowerCase(), userAddress: data.userAddress, userNumber: data.userNumber, userPassword:data.userPassword}
    con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?;", newAccount.userEmail , (err, result)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        test = result;
        if (result.length === 0) {
            let cartID = 0;
            con.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newAccount , function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(data);
            });
            res.redirect("/login");
        }
        else {
            req.flash("errors", "Email already in use, please try again");
            res.redirect("/register");
        }
    });
```

the table look like this, [user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQqVL.png) it have a column call userID which is auto increment. the okPacket returned from "INSERT INTO users SET ?" contain that data [the data i want to extract is called insertID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDYbB.png). I want to extract that data to do stuff with it, but whatever i did, it was logged into console as undefined.is there anyway to do that, because i dont want to have to many queries to the database. Thanks everyone for your time!

I have tried some approaches but still failed. I expected to extract the data called insertID in okPacket